# Прогресс-бар в процентах для команды tar в Windows 10

Tags: cmd, bat, powershell

На днях написал скрипт, который делает backup моих данных. Всё работает, НО! Мне нужен прогресс-бар, чтобы не гадать, сколько осталось времени. Архивация моих данных базируется на команде tar (пример: Выполнено: 22%). Я понимаю, что нужно с прогонкой через циклы всё это сделать, но не получается. Везде облазил - не нашёл ответа. Прошу помощи у вас. Если же нет ответа на данного вопроса, то можно с xcopy или с robocopy (в крайнем случае powershell). Благодарю заранее.
P.S. Мой первый вопрос на Stack.

Comment: Ты хочешь прогресс конкретной проги или в принципе решить эту проблему для любой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Многие инструменты имеют встроенные опции для вывода прогресса выполнения.

Например, у tar:

```
--checkpoint[=N]
      Display progress messages every Nth record (default 10).
```

Обычно это вывод на стандартный поток ошибок, не забудте перенаправить.